# Android Test Case with Appium

Tags: java, android, eclipse, coded-ui-tests, appium

Does anyone know how to run Appium Testcase on Windows using Eclipse.

My question is. How Can I run a Test case for an .apk which is already installed on my android device.

Because the sample I am working with, it will install the apk everytime a testcase run.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    File appDir = new File("src/Test");
    File app = new File(appDir, "MyTest.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, ""); //Name of mobile web browser to automate. Should be an empty string if automating an app instead.
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.TuneBox.Rokki");
    capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", ".MyTest");

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your app installed on the device - otherwise you will receive

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Then just remove `MobileCapabilityType.APP`capability from your code. Appium will launch the previously installed app.